# Gluten free gumbo

Tags: gluten-free, gumbo

I'd like to make a gluten free gumbo for some friends.  Is it possible to make a dark roux with the right flavor with rice flour?  Any other suggestions?  I'd like something point and shoot, as I dont want to be cooking for hours with a disappointing result.  I'm sure if it tanks, my friends will appreciatecthe effort, but I'd rather have it work!

Comment: Please check this recipe: https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/01/gluten-free-tuesday-roux-rice-flour.html

Comment: @zetaprime  Thanks.  I was looking at that one, but had reservations when it said it would darken after 5 minutes.  That doesn't feel right, or at least different enough to make it worth asking about.  I'm looking for mahogany.

Comment: That darkening is due to milk solids in the butter caramelizing/browning (actually maillard reaction). You can control it, at some point it will get mahogany, I believe. Why don't you just try to roux only, before doing the whole thing.

Comment: Good idea.  If it misses, I'm only a half hour in.

Comment: @zetaprime, I'm sure that browning of milk solids contributes something to the color of a roux, that can't be all, because a roux will also brown nicely when made with vegetable oil or baconfat.

Comment: You can also brown flour in advance, in an oven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made Gumbo with rice flour. Seemed like it took a little longer to get a nice chocolate roux, but otherwise no change in recipe or technique.

In my case it was a chicken-and-andouille gumbo, but I would not hesitate to do the same with a seafood gumbo if a similar occasion (party with a known guest with Celiac disease) arose.

Comment: Lee, could you add some details on how you've used rice flour to make a dark roux? Other ingredients, ratios, temperatures, method... all would make your answer much more useful. Thank you!